# composer package : how to require vendor lib autoload

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I've opened an issue almost a year ago about a composer package I love : jobby (it allows to manage CRON tasks in PHP) : [see issue](https://github.com/hellogerard/jobby/issues/22)

My problem with this package is that the composer vendor's lib is hardcoded in a file named BackgroundJob.php ( [see file](https://github.com/hellogerard/jobby/blob/master/src/Jobby/BackgroundJob.php#L292) )

```
if (file_exists('vendor/autoload.php')) {
    require('vendor/autoload.php');
} else {
    require(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__DIR__))))) . '/vendor/autoload.php');
}
```

But my vendor directory is not "vendor" but "php/lib" and it is not negociable ;)

My ugly solution is to hard code path to autoload file but I then have to manually edit BackgroundJob.php each time I install the lib.

As vendor lib can be any depth, I am really wandering what is THE GOOD solution to this problem : obviously Jobby is not the only package which requires others libraries from composer to be run. Could you point me on a library which handles that so I can have a look at it or give me your thoughts ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no clean nor THE GOOD solution to install a package you don't own yourself into another directory than `vendor` because it is a very bad idea. And this is by design of composer! This is one thing that makes composer awesome. There is a [nice article](https://igor.io/2013/09/04/composer-vendor-directory.html) about why it is a bad idea to install packages into a directory other than `vendor`.

If you have really good reasons that are not just "but I want to ..." and you really really need to do that (I would recommend not doing it!) but then you can do some tricks with [composer scripts](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md). It should be possible to run a `post-package-update` or `post-package-install` script to move the package from vendor to your desired directory.

But keep in mind every developer will hate you for doing this. There are reasons why `vendor` is the one and only directory for third party packages. This is not a restriction just for fun.

Comment: I understand your explanation but when I began working with composer I saw the "vendor-dir" option was available. If it is mandatory for some libs to use this directory, it should be removed or at least but a very big warning flag on it ! ?

Comment: But the `vendor-dir` option is not meant for users to install into another directory than `vendor`. May I ask you why your project uses `php/lib` instead of `vendor` even if you said that it is not negotiable? Maybe it is easier to change that than screwing up all the advantages of composer.

Answer (score 0):

Here a bad solution but do the trick:

fork that project => change codes => make your custom package

later, you can just install your own custom package.

Comment: Year I thought about it and then I told myself : go try to do it the good way :)